# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file [When I using Keras and not PILLOW]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I have this error

"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3008, in open
raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000027A8D41B770>

When I run this code:

```html
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os


# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 1e-4
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

DIRECTORY = r"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Escritorio\To lenovo\Escritorio\Tesis\Tesis Project\Face-Mask-Detection\dataset"

CATEGORIES = ["with_mask", "without_mask"]

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
data = []
labels = []

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
        image = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        image = img_to_array(image)
        image = preprocess_input(image)

        data.append(image)
        labels.append(category)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the MobileNetV2 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are
# left off
baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving mask detector model...")
model.save("mask_detector V2.model", save_format="h5")

# plot the training loss and accuracy
N = EPOCHS
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

This code is supposed to generate a .model file that will be used for face mask on a video or webcam. And usses two datasets, one with people wearing a face mask and the other with people without face mask.

As far as I know, Im not using PILLOW or PIL, so I have no clue why do I get this message.
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: This error is due to a corrupt file or file with an incorrect extension that the generator is not able to read, you are not using **PIL** directly, because `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image` load images as `PIL`  *format*.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **ellhe-blaster**, this error is due to a corrupt file or file with an incorrect extension that the generator is not able to read, you are not using PIL directly, because `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image` load images as `PIL` format

You can find the list of faulty images with the following code and removing those images from your dataset will help.

```
import PIL
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import UnidentifiedImageError

path = Path("INSERT PATH HERE").rglob("*.jpeg")
for img_p in path:
    try:
        img = PIL.Image.open(img_p)
    except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError:
            print(img_p)
```